# Angular Apollo GraphQL watchQuery vs subscription

Tags: angular, graphql, graphqlclient

I am new to GraphQL and need some help...

As I see there is a plenty of components in GraphQL such as Query, Mutation and Subscription. In Angular Apollo Client I have two methods to deal with Query: apollo.query and apollo.watchQuery. As I understand query method gets the data only once when watchQuery constantly watches for updates. And if so what is the difference between watchQuery and GraphQl subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the oficial [apollo docs](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/subscriptions/): "GraphQL subscriptions are a way to push data from the server to the clients that choose to listen to real time messages from the server. Subscriptions are similar to queries in that they specify a set of fields to be delivered to the client, but instead of immediately returning a single answer, a result is sent every time a particular event happens on the server."

So the subscription is just listening for some push alterations from the backend, and instead, the watchQuery is a query that whenever that query will be refetched or the data related to that query is changed from anywhere else, this method will keep on emitting the updated data.

I dont know if you are confusing watchQuery with "live query", but live queries are not supported yet.